# Database connection pg_hba.conf

Tags: azure, psql, pg-hba.conf

When i'm trying to my database in Azure from intelij i always getting this error:
PS Access in Azure is on

> The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [28000] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "37.140.21.90", user "xxx", database "xxx", SSL on

my pg_hba.conf:

> host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
>
> host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
>
> host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
>
> host    all             all            all                 md5
>
> local   all             all                                     trust

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the result of SSL activated on your managed Azure DB.

To solve it there are two options:

1- Deactivate SSL on the Azure database side.

2- Add hostssl in your pg_hba.conf file so that host records match SSL connection attempts.

The line will be like:

```
hostssl database  user  address  auth-method  [auth-options]
```

Comment: Did you get the same error? even with SSL deactivated?

Comment: Yes, getting the same. I tryed with and without SSL

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host Did you checked this link?